# Do I require a work permit for the US if I have a B1/B2 Visa

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas, working-visas

I have a B1/B2 USA Visa, I’m do work for a non US company that pays me as an entertainer/cultural perform. I am asked to work in the US at conference in this role. Do I require a special visa for this. I am not getting paid by a US company but by non US Company hired to bring in a performer for their conference TIA

Comment: This sounds like it's for a short-term visit so, even though it's about working, I don't think it's off-topic, here.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you need a different visa for that, perhaps a [P visa](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/employment/temporary-worker-visas.html).